# No module named ib.message

Tags: python, git

I am trying to set up IBPY and Python on my Mac to run with Interactive Brokers. I have installed Git. I created a subdirectory ibapi under Home. I downloaded IBPy using `git clone https://github.com/blampe/IbPy` from the ibapi directory.

I am now trying to run the Demo.py program in Spyder.  When I choose Run, I receive the error message:

```
ImportError: No module named Ib.Message
```

The first few lines of the demo program are:

```
import os
import sys
import time

import Ib.Message
import Ib.Socket
import Ib.Type
```

I am also trying to run a sample program: ib_api_demo from http://www.quantstart.com/articles/Using-Python-IBPy-and-the-Interactive-Brokers-API-to-Automate-Trades.  When I try to run this, I get the error message:

```
ImportError: No module named ib.ext.Contract
```

The first few lines are:

```
from ib.ext.Contract import Contract
from ib.ext.Order import Order
from ib.opt import Connection, message
```

Comment: Did you do a `python setup.py install`, as python may not search your home directory, and if it searched your home, the folder would have to be called `Ib` or `ib`.

Comment: Yes, I did a Python setup.py install.  In my Home folder, I have a folder ibapi. I did the setup.py install inside \ibapi\ibPy\. My "Python" program, however, is located in my Anaconda folder.  Should I move it?

Comment: So its not installed at the python libs folder?

Comment: What should be installed at the python libs folder?  I see a Anaconda\lib folder.  It has a folder called python2.7 inside of that.  Where should my Python program be?

Comment: Inside of the python2.7 folder, I see a folder called "ib" and inside this a folder called "ext".  It looks like my Spyder programs need to be point to the Anaconda folder.  But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, as I don't use anaconda. If nobody else answers, I'll have a look.

Comment: I moved Spyder and Spyder.ini into the Anaconda folder.  Then I restarted Spyder.  This got ib_api_demo.py to run ok.  But when I try to run demo.py, I get the error message:

No Python console is currently selected to run Demo.py.

Please select or open a new Python console and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.  The problem was I was launching Spyder from my Mac Finder.  When I did this, I received the error messages.  When I launched Spyder (actually Anaconda Python) by typing "Spyder" in the Terminal window, this launched Anaconda Python.  From here, I could run all my programs successfully with no errors.